# How do I position my .NET Maui Frame at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: xaml, maui, .net-maui

```
<Frame BorderColor="#2f3136"
          CornerRadius="20"
          BackgroundColor="#2f212b"
          Grid.Row="0">
                
               <Editor x:Name="inputBox" 
                       Placeholder="Enter your message (2000 characters max)"
                       TextChanged="inputBox_Changed"
                       Completed="inputBox_Completed"
                       MaxLength="2000"
                       Keyboard="Chat"
                       AutoSize="TextChanges"/>
            
            </Frame>
```

The Frame sits at the top of the screen, how do I make it do the opposite, and sit at the bottom of the screen instead?

Comment: It helps to know what kind of container it’s enclosed in.  Generally speaking, you set the VerticalOptions property to control the vertical layout

Comment: This is all in a VerticalStackLayout. I can't really set the VerticalOptions property, when I did VerticalOptions="End", it did nothing at all.

Comment: is the VerticalStackLayout filling the entire page?  When you say you "can't" set VerticalOptions, do you mean it won't let you, or that you do it and it doesn't have any effect?

Answer (score 1):

Just as jason said, it would be helpful to know what kind of container it’s enclosed in.

From your code ,we know that you should use `Grid` out of the `Frame`.
In this condition, we can set the `Frame`  as the last row of the Grid.

And set the other part of the Gird to occupy all the remaining position of the screen.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<Grid Margin="20,35,20,20"> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Green" 
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                 Grid.Row="0">
                   
    </StackLayout>
           
    <Frame BorderColor="#2f3136" 
      CornerRadius="20"
      BackgroundColor="#2f212b" 
           
      HeightRequest="100"
      Grid.Row="1"
      VerticalOptions="End" >
        <Editor x:Name="inputBox" 
                   Placeholder="Enter your message (2000 characters max)"
                   MaxLength="2000"
                   Keyboard="Chat"
                   AutoSize="TextChanges"/>

    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Note:

1.Suppose there are two rows, I set the `Grid.Row` of `Frame`  to `1` and add the following property:

```
VerticalOptions="End"
```

2.I set the height of the first row to `*`

```
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```